# Perfect Update query not working in VB.net with Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-update

I am searching this since two days and didn't get any result. I am developing the application in VB.Net and using access as my database. In that I am trying to update the password in my application. I am trying a simple query in my application which throws an Exception. 
[image]

I have checked my database, field names are perfect and I also tried this same query in access it was working fine. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word PASSWORD is a reserved keyword for MS-Access. You can use it only if you enclose in square brackets

```
Update Login SET [Password] = '....' WHERE UserName = '....'
```